# How do I add the directory path as another Column to my dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, os.walk

I am using this python script to get csv files with particular name in sub-directories of my folder and reading them into dataframe, I have been trying to add their directory paths as another column to the dataframe but i keep encountering errors.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

path = 'main/directory/path'
file_extension = '.csv'
csv_file_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        if name.startswith("FileName.csv"):
            file_path = os.path.join(root, name)
            csv_file_list.append(file_path)

            #print(file_path)
        #data = pd.concat(csv_file_list, ignore_index=True)



dfs = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in csv_file_list]

print(dfs)
```

How can I add the directory paths for where each of these files are found as another column in the data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read and append the path to the df as a new column in the loop itself.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

path = 'main/directory/path'
file_extension = '.csv'
dfs= []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        if name.startswith("FileName.csv"):
            file_path = os.path.join(root, name)
            df=pd.read_csv(file_path)
            df["file_path"] = str(file_path)
            dfs.append(df)
dfs = pd.concat(dfs)
print(dfs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you're looking for

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

path = 'main/directory/path'
file_extension = '.csv'
csv_file_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        if name.startswith("FileName.csv"):
            file_path = os.path.join(root, name)
            csv_file_list.append(file_path)

            #print(file_path)
        #data = pd.concat(csv_file_list, ignore_index=True)



dfs = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in csv_file_list]
dfs = [df[i].insert(0,"file_path",csv_file_list[i]) for i in range(len(dfs))]

print(dfs)
```

you can concat your dataframes as well

```
df_concated = pd.concat(dfs)
print(df_concated)
```